# Alternative to deprecated AuditReader#getCurrentRevision method

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am migrating a java application from Spring Boot 1.5 to Spring Boot 2.2.3 and this involves upgrading Hibernate/Envers to 5.4.10.Final.

The existing code calls AuditReader#getCurrentRevision(Class revisionEntityClass, boolean persist) which is deprecated and the JavaDocs state to use RevisionListener but this does not do the same thing as we need to fetch the revision that **will be** created when the existing transaction commits. The getCurrentRevision method gave us that functionality but the RevisionListener is not invoked until after our code needs the revision number and also the revisionEntity passed to the RevisionListener#newRevision  method does not yet have its id set. RevisionListener seems to be targetted more towards setting additional information on the revision entity rather than obtaining information from it.

How can I obtain the revision that will be created as part of the current transaction?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate in more detail on why you need the revision number?  Are you using a field on your entity mappings to store this value?  If that's indeed the case, perhaps a better solution might be for Envers to provide an annotation that can be used for value generation, like `@CreationTimestamp` works in ORM and it would automatically allocate the revision number early and guarantee that it gets stored in the entity without any user code needing to worry with it.

Comment: Hi @Naros ... we store the revision on an entity that gets processed as part of end of day processing. By doing this we are able to access the account state at the time the event happened.

Comment: @Naros Your comment does make me wonder though if a suitable approach might be to use the RevisionListener. A threadlocal would allow us to set a value on the revision entity that we could then use with our AuditReader instead of the actual revision. Something to look into, thanks.

Comment: Then it sounds like the annotation value generator idea might work for you.  This is also something that users often ask for anyway, storing the revision number from Envers in the entity itself and so this takes care of both.  I'll see whats involved this week and hopefully get it into 5.4.11 for testing.

Comment: Thanks Naros. Note from my "answer" below that we now have something working that is reasonably clean. At the same time however we are still just investigating the upgrade so if the alternative that you propose is something you wish to offer anyway then it would be interesting to see how well it fits our use case. I am presuming that it would require the event entity to be audited in which case it comes very close to the workaround that I posted below but without requiring the overhead of the lookup via AuditReader when processing the event.

Answer (score 0):

To add some context ... we needed to store the current revision on an entity representing an event so that the event could be replayed at end of day and access the state of an account as it was at the time of the event.

In our previous (Spring Boot 1.5) version of the application we did not audit the event entities because we had no need to.

To work around the functionality being deprecated and thus marked for removal we simply started auditing the event entity. This way we are able to access the revision of the event entity insert at the time that we are processing the event rather than when we insert it and that gives us the revision for the state of the account at the time the event was raised.

Not an answer as such to my original question but a clean solution to the functional requirement.